# What possessive is used when "everybody" is the antecedent?

Tags: personal-pronouns, gender-neutral, singular-they, indefinite-pronouns, possessive-determiners

Is this sentence right?

> Everybody is wasting **his** time.

Is  *his* or *its* the possessive of *everybody*?

Most people use *his* but in my opinion it should be *its*:

> Everybody is wasting **its** time.

I want to know what experts say about this.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 'Everybody is wasting _their_ time' uses the gender- neutral plural.

Answer (score 1):

## Animacy, not Gender

If you don’t know what someone’s gender is, you cannot call them an “it”, for “it” is not about gender. It is therefore ungrammatical in English to use *its* to refer to a human being, whether you know their gender or not.

That's because *it* is not some sort of marker of gender in English but rather a marker of ***animacy*** — that is, of agency and sentience. The [Wikipedia article on Animacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy) observes that:

> The distinction between *he*, *she*, and other personal pronouns, on one hand, and *it*, on the other hand is a distinction in **animacy in English** and in many Indo-European languages.

So it turns out that the issue of [“animates-vs-inanimates” trumps the 
“battle of the sexes”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/204233/2085) in English. Here are some examples:

- If you say that everyone is wasting **your** time, that means that you are the one whose time is being wasted.
- If you say that everyone is wasting **my** time, that means that I am the one whose time is being wasted.
- If you say that everyone is wasting **her** time, that means that she is the one whose time is being wasted.
- If you say that everyone is wasting **their** time, that either means that they are each one of them wasting their own time individually, or else that there exists some group whose time is being collectively wasted (which may or may not match the subject).

You cannot use *it* for people.  To do so is confusingly ungrammatical or offensive, or both.

Here from the [Wikipedia article on English personal pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_personal_pronouns#Complete_table) is a simple chart explaining this:

[image: Charts of English personal pronouns]